# ELMAH missing connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am trying to configure [ELmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to work with my mvc app.

The error says

```
Connection string is missing for the SQL error log
```

But I checked my Web.config and the connectionString was there. I am not sure what is causing the problem. In the ErrorLogPage.cs, the connectionString always has null value

```
 public SqlErrorLog(IDictionary config)
        {
            if (config == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

            string connectionString = ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString(config);

            //
            // If there is no connection string to use then throw an 
            // exception to abort construction.
            //

            if (connectionString.Length == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException("Connection string is missing for the SQL error log.");

            _connectionString = connectionString;

            ...
        }
```

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sql-elmah" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx" />
    <add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=yyy;Initial Catalog=yyy;user=yyy;password=yyy;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="sql-elmah" />
  </elmah>

  <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>

      <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <modules>
      <add name="Elmah.ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you really instantiating `SqlErrorLog` with an `IDictionary`? The more likely case is you are instantiating it with the `string` constructor...make sure you are using the proper value for that string?

Comment: Is there any chance that a CONFIG transform or similar is causing confusion about the actual 'IN-effect" config?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted Elmah reference. Adding Elmah reference again by clicking the "Manage Nuget Package" button. Browse online for "Elmah" and install. After that, the error changed to "Fail to load System.Data.SQLite". I used the same process to install SQLite. The problem was fixed